# can we link google+ page instead of google+ profile in google authership

Tags: google-plus

I want to link my Google plus page instead of google plus profile for www.electricaltechnology.org in google plus authorship...Will it work?
in simple words...
can we link google+ page instead of google+ profile in google authership

Answer (score 0):

Authorship only works for profiles - but for pages you can add

```
<link rel="publisher" href="page-url-goes-here" />
```

in the head of the page to link your web page with your Google+ page. If you point your Google+ page at your domain, this will enable a tick on your page for a verified URL, but it wont add a profile picture to the search result. More at https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713826?hl=en-GB